# C++ Message Passing Library like MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, message-passing

i am currently implementing a message-assing based implementation to offload compute-intense work to another node with an GPU equipped.
So i got a master/slave model where the host generates data and wants it to be computed with on the slave (+ attached GPU).
I have implemented this so far using OpenMPI where i start my program on these 2 nodes and send the data via message passing.
What i want to do now is to change the implementation of the slave so it runs permanently and waits for data until SOME host connects to it. And this host might be a windows or linux host.
So I dont want to start master&slave with mpirun, but just the host normally and want it to connect at runtime to my slave.
Another requirement is that I use templated classes which size I do not know at compile-time. I started creating a simple TCP-protocol which was just a struct with a message tag (unsigned short) and the payload/data (as a union) in it. Here was the problem that I could not use templated classes in the union (which makes sense).

So, to solve my problem I am looking for a message-passing high-level library with MPI-like syntax at optimum. Is there any way to do this?
Like to use MPI but not mpirun and instead connect to other processes at runtime.

Comment: zeromq comes to mind

Comment: 0mq perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroMQ

Comment: @David, Severin: zeromq's creator released its replacement, nanomsg

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, good to know

Answer (score 1):

MPI does provide a facility for connecting server/client processes. This is discussed in section 10.4 of [the standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), one use-case is:

> A server wants to accept connections from multiple clients. Both clients and server may be parallel programs.

Basically this involves, `MPI_Open_port` / `MPI_Comm_accept` on the server, and `MPI_Comm_connect` on the client-side. There are some (Name Publishing) for establishing connections.

However, it seems to be a rarely used feature and I am not sure how good the different implementations handle that. Even the standard warns, this is not meant to be a particularly robust solution.

While Boost.MPI does not seem to support that directly, it should be possible to still use Boost.MPI for the actual communication, when you establish the connection with the C interface.

Comment: Open MPI implements it. The problem is that `MPI_Comm_accept` is a blocking call and there is no equivalent to `select(2)`. Which means that the server must either process clients one by one or be threaded. And multithreading with MPI, especially at `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`, is yet another can of worms.